# Leaderboard score submission

Tags: android, leaderboard

I have a game on android and it seems to be a problem with score submission: it somehow ignores a high score (I have a leaberboard based on time: the lowest time is the best). Here is my code:

```
public void submitScore(int difficulty, long time) {
    Log.e(TAG, "difficulty: " + difficulty + "; api connected: " + getApiClient().isConnected() + "; time: " + time);
    if (getApiClient().isConnected()) {
        time = time * 1000;
        if (difficulty == Constants.DIFFICULTY_EASY) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), Constants.LEADERBOARD_ID_EASY, time).setResultCallback(new MyLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback());
        } else if (difficulty == Constants.DIFFICULTY_MEDIUM) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), Constants.LEADERBOARD_ID_MEDIUM, time).setResultCallback(new MyLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback());
        } else if (difficulty == Constants.DIFFICULTY_HARD) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), Constants.LEADERBOARD_ID_HARD, time).setResultCallback(new MyLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback());
        } else if (difficulty == Constants.DIFFICULTY_IMPOSSIBLE) {
            Games.Leaderboards.submitScoreImmediate(getApiClient(), Constants.LEADERBOARD_ID_IMPOSSIBLE, time).setResultCallback(new MyLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback());
        }
    }
}

 class MyLeaderBoardSubmitScoreCallback implements ResultCallback<Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult> {
    @Override
    public void onResult(Leaderboards.SubmitScoreResult res) {
        if (res.getStatus().getStatusCode() == 0) {
            Log.e("TAG", "score submitted successfully: " + res.getScoreData().toString());
        } else{
            Log.e("TAG", "error submitting score: " + res.getScoreData().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is what is printed from callback:

score submitted successfully: ScoreSubmissionData{PlayerId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, StatusCode=0, TimesSpan=DAILY, Result=Result{RawScore=70000, FormattedScore=1:10, ScoreTag=null, NewBest=false}, TimesSpan=WEEKLY, Result=Result{RawScore=73000, FormattedScore=1:13, ScoreTag=null, NewBest=false}, TimesSpan=ALL_TIME, Result=Result{RawScore=135000, FormattedScore=2:15, ScoreTag=null, NewBest=false}}

My new score was 35 seconds so I submitted 35000...

Am I doing something wrong?
Because if I look at highscores from my app, my best time is 02:15 (135 seconds)... so what are these weekly, daily timespans?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution ?

Comment: No, I have't found the solution yet